# What software besides PowerPoint can put all the pictures together into one movie and play them as one motion picture?

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, animation, slideshow, windows-movie-maker

I have a lot of jpg files that are all just like film frames of one motion film, so I want to connect them together into one movie - is there any software besides PowerPoint that can make it?

If you recommend "Movie Maker", then would you please tell me how to make the time span between two picture frames there less than 5 seconds, because I've already tried it and found that the shortest time span between two picture frames there is only 5 seconds - perhaps I don't understand something there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Photo lapse](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/create-avi-movie-file-from-jpeg-images/) sounds promising. But i have no windows installed and can't try it. Here is even a [Video](http://vimeo.com/1226517) description on how it works.

Comment: Very nice suggestion! Seems to be easy to use.

Comment: Thank you, Darokthar!!! Just installed it and am using it at the moment. Very nice peace of software. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Movie Maker

Download
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/updates/moviemaker2.mspx

How to
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/moviemaker/default.mspx